# AutoSys Xit Code -655

Tags: autosys

I'm totally new to AutoSys and have been muddling my way around.
I've managed to figure out that the job I sent to the AutoSys Server is failing and the Exit Code is -655.
Can anyone please tell me what that means?

Answer (score 1):

If you are bound to active directory for security then a 655 can mean

1. Account not defined to Active Directory
2. Account not defined to autosys_secure table
3. Password in autosys_secure does not match password in Active Directory
4. Active directory account lockout
5. Active directory account disabled
6. Active directory batch account restricted to a different server

There are more security violations that can trigger this error. These are the most common.
655 is always some security related issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that  the below are working fine

autoping -m (machine name) - Autoping is successful

autorep -m (machine name)  This should return as machine is Online

Answer (score 0):

Per Appendix A of the Unicenter AutoSys Job Management for UNIX and Windows Reference Guide:

> -655 (SYSTEM_ERROR) => STARTJOB failures because auto_remote will not start.

Somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the profile in the job does not match an existing profile. In my case, it was due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://comm.support.ca.com/kb/exitcode-655-on-windows-system-agent/kb000006112

> EXITCODE: -655 on Windows System Agent

Document ID : KB000006112
Last Modified Date : 14/02/2018
Show Technical Document Details

**Issue:**

We have installed a 11.3 System Agent successful on a Windows system. 
Autoping works fine. User and password are defined within autosys_secure.

Test job is submitted and ends with exitcode -655.

```
[03/08/2017 10:06:53] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: FORCE_STARTJOB JOB: testjob 

[03/08/2017 10:06:53] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS STATUS: STARTING JOB: testjob MACHINE: win_agent 

[03/08/2017 10:06:54] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: ALARM ALARM: STARTJOBFAIL JOB: testjob MACHINE: win_agent

[03/08/2017 10:06:54] <Owner attribute error. User does not exist in the system> 

[03/08/2017 10:07:04] CAUAJM_I_40245 EVENT: CHANGE_STATUS STATUS: FAILURE JOB: testjob MACHINE: win_agent EXITCODE: -655
```

**Environment:**

11.3 SP7 System Agent on Windows

**Cause:**

Machine definition contains wrong node_name.

**Resolution:**

Adapt machine definition with correct node_name.